Mulesoft Policy configuration failed. We cannot reproduce the configuration step for this policy due to technical constraints
I am writing a policy.yaml file for the developing a message logging custom policy on mulesoft; This yaml file basically serves as a UI for the policy. After I have applied the policy and click on policy > edit configuration, I get an error "Policy configuration failed". Here is my yaml file
#%Policy Definition 0.1
id: custom-policy-test
name: custom-policy-test
description: THIS IS A TEST POLICY
category: Custom
type: custom
resourceLevelSupported: true
encryptionSupported: false
standalone: true
requiredCharacteristics: []
providedCharacteristics: []
configuration:
  - propertyName: ClickMe
  - name: Radio test 
  - description: Click here to enable below expression
  - optional: true
  - type: boolean


Here is the screenshot for the error that I see 
Versions:
Mule4
minRuntimeVersion: 4.1.1
maxRuntimeVersion: 4.4.0
Any thoughts?
